# How to use zend model class inside a namespace in ZF1

Tags: php, zend-framework, namespaces, models

I have created a namespace outside my models folder in ZF1. Now I want to establish the db connection in the created namespace and for that I want to use the existing model classes.

While creating the object of model class its throwing error "class not found".

below is the sample

### Model file:

```
class Application_Model_Fetchdetails extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    public function getDetails(){
        // model code here to fetch the data from database
    }
}
```

### namespace file:

```
namespace Product\Fetch;
class fetchData  {

    function __construct() {
        $this->Obj = new Application_Model_Fetchdetails();
    }

    /**
     * function will fetch the data
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        try {
           $data = $this->Obj->getDetails("col","id='A1'");
           return $data;
        } catch(Zend_Exception $e) {
            echo "error".$e->getMessage(); die;
        }
    }
```

its showing error in getData function and in the constructor while creating object saying class not found

Answer (score 0):

Because you namespaced the class with `Product\Fetch`, it is automatically namespacing your model. You need to add the following:

```
namespace Product\Fetch;

use \Application_Model_Fetchdetails; // ADD THIS

class fetchData  {
   // ...
}
```